# Protocol Oriented Programming Optional Functions

Tags: swift

I am trying to deep dive into Protocol Oriented Programming with Swift. That`s why i am playing with two inherited protocols as situation 1 and situation 2. These are my protocols:

```
  protocol Father {
        func helpPeople(input: Any) // function A
    }
    
    protocol Son: Father {
        associatedtype Responsibility
        func helpPeople(input: Responsibility) // function B
    }
```

---

**situation 1**: no compiler warning. so **assumption 1:** Compiler is ignoring function B. Function B conforming is enough for Guy struct.

```
struct Guy: Son {
    func helpPeople(input: Any) {}
}
```

---

**situation 2**: compiler warning! Type 'Guy' does not conform to protocol 'Father' **assumption 2:** This is related static or dynamic dispatch ?

```
struct Repair {}

struct Guy: Son {
    
    typealias Responsibility = Repair

    func helpPeople(input: Repair) {}
}
```

assumption 1 and 2 is true or should i elaborate different approaches?

Comment: Sorry to be slow, but what exactly is the question you're asking?

Comment: oh my bad. i forgot ask the question

Comment: When you say "elaborate different approaches," approaches to what? What is the actual goal? What existing, concrete code has duplication that you're trying to remove? Generally the only use of PATs (protocols with associated types) is to allow you to create generic extensions (i.e. algorithms that work on the type). What extensions would you write to Son?

Comment: @Rob i just wonder how i should think about protocols. Thanks for your answer i am thinking on your sentences

Comment: You should think of protocols (particularly PATs) as "first concrete, then generic." Start with concrete types. Look for how they overlap and generic algorithms that you could write that you currently duplicate with "almost the same, but slightly different code." From there, you will find protocols you can extract. Do not think of PATs like "class inheritance with generics, but for structs." That's not what they're for, and not how they work. You may find this helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXwJg0QTlZE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In situation 1, `Responsibility == Any`, so both protocols are fulfilled.

In situation 2, you've implemented one requirement (Son), but not the other (Father). Father requires the method that accepts Any, and Guy doesn't implement that.

"Inheriting" a protocol just means "in order to conform to this protocol, a type must also conform to this other protocol." It's nothing like subclassing.

This design of protocols is probably very unhelpful, so I wouldn't continue down this road. If you find yourself passing around `Any` in a protocol, you're probably on a bad path already. This is not Protocol Oriented Programming. It's just "defining some protocols." But this is why it compiles or doesn't.

Comment: Thanks but are you sure about "bad path" ? There are some approaches called shadow type erasures which is used that kind of Any passing a protocol function

Comment: I admit I've never heard of a "shadow type eraser." (And I've been teaching about type erasers for years. https://robnapier.net/erasure) I'd be happy to see what you have in mind that isn't a bad path. The only protocol I know that comes close to this is `_AnyHashableBox`, which is an extreme corner case. https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/AnyHashable.swift#L40-L57

Comment: Thank you for links i will check out. I am trying to learn from this pattern from here. Also some medium articles they called as shadow type erasure
https://fabernovel.github.io/2020-06-03/approaches-to-type-erasure-in-swift

Comment: I do not like that design at all. There are much better ways to do this. The `configure` method quietly does nothing if you pass it the wrong type. That breaks the whole point of static type checking. Instead, this could be much better implemented with closures (or a simple struct that wraps a closure). In the given example, ShadowCellConfigurable is an elaborate and weakly typed way to wrap a simpler and stronger `(ViewModel) -> Void`. I think protocols were used here because "Swift is protocol oriented" rather than because protocols are useful here.